# Parse migration tool stuck after canceling

Tags: parse-platform

So I have started the migration process from parse db to a mongolab db. The migration needed to be canceled at the verify stage. After pressing cancel, the migration tool is now stuck on the verify phase with no way to restart.

Has anyone else ran into this issue or have any ideas on how to restart the migration tool? Thanks ahead of time.

What I have attempted:

Removing and creating a new MongoLab DB

Multiple browsers

Logout/login

[Parse Migration Tool Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laoI8.png)

Comment: Add some info/code on how you were doing the migration. hard to understand the problem without seeing it.

Comment: The migration tool is managed by parse.com, no code included. This is more of a troubleshooting Parse.com's migration tool question. 
Set the migration tool's destination URl to my mongoDB and pressed run. The data did the copying but is not allowing the option to restart after canceling. 
Migrated using mongodburl:
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@<mydbinfo>

Comment: After cruising around this seems to be an issue others have ran into.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/tPLTxNUf8Uo

Comment: Can consider an alternative solution too for the migration strategy, where migrating over to Couchbase and using Couchbase Mobile may be better overall.  I wrote up part 1 of a blog here:  

http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/migration-from-parse-to-couchbase

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been fixed on the parse side.  But if it still happens, you have contact parse directly using the job id.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/42

> We discussed this here and basically in order to deal with migration
>   issues, we need you to individually report a bug through
>   parse.com/help. This allows each of you to get individual support,
>   from a team who can escalate issues, and for us to be able to ask up
>   front for specific information which will help us handle your issue.
>   We're exposing the 'job id' for the migration in the UI, and that is
>   something you should provide if you're having a problem.
>
> Going to close this issue. For problems involving migration, or any
>   issues not specific to parse-server, please visit
>   https://parse.com/help and find the bug icon / "Something wrong?"
>   section to start the bug reporting flow.